# Prove that a polynomial of this form has a real root of this form.

Tags: reference-request, polynomials, recurrence-relations, roots

Prove or disprove that for positive coefficients:

$$a_k>0$$

this polynomial:

$$a_1x^0+a_2x^1+a_3x^2+a_4x^3+...+a_nx^{n-1}-x^n=0$$

has a real root $x$ that is the fraction from the following linearly recursive sequence:

$$t(0)=1,\;\;t(1)=1,\;\;t(2)=1,\;\;t(3)=1,\;...\;,t(n)=1$$
$$t(n)=\sum_{k=1}^{k=n} a_{n-(k-1)}*t(m - k)$$

where $$m=\text{degree of polynomial}$$

$$x=\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty}\frac{t(n)}{t(n-1)}$$

Please refer to this Mathematica 8 program:

```
Clear[t, n, nn, x]
nnn=5;
a = Table[RandomReal[WorkingPrecision -> 50], {n, 1, nnn}];
Print["polynomial:"]
Total[Flatten[{a*Table[x^(n - 1), {n, 1, nnn}], -1*x^nnn}]]
Print["polynomial degree:"]
nn = Length[a]
mm = 1000;
t[0] = 1;
t[1] = 1;
t[2] = 1;
t[3] = 1;
t[4] = 1;
t[n_] := t[n] = 
   a[[5 - (5 - 1)]]*t[n - 5] + a[[5 - (4 - 1)]]*t[n - 4] + 
    a[[5 - (3 - 1)]]*t[n - 3] + a[[5 - (2 - 1)]]*t[n - 2] + 
    a[[5 - (1 - 1)]]*t[n - 1];
Print["If the following two numbers are equal then the ratio has \
probably converged:"]
N[t[mm - 1]/t[mm - 2], 50]
x = N[t[mm]/t[mm - 1], 50]
Print["If this number is zero then x is a root of the polynomial \
above"]
Sum[a[[n]]*x^(n - 1), {n, 1, nn}] - x^nn
```

in case the latex is incorrect for the sum in the recurrence.
The program shows the solution for the quintic case.

Also if you can make the restrictions on the coefficients more precise (broader) than this I would be happy.

Comment: Not sure I am following.  You appear to have two definitions for $t(n)$...on the first hand, it is $1$.  On the other it is some sum.  And the sum only appears to make sense up to the degree of the polynomial (for which all the $t(i)$ are $1$ anyway.  And I suppose that $a(i)=a_i$?

Comment: I suspected that the sum is wrong. Are you able to interpret my program?

Comment: I am confused by my own notation.

Comment: The program looks clear enough.  The problem with your notation is that you keep using the index $n$ with different meanings.  Following the program, you have a polynomial of your form  of degree $6$ and you want the recursion $$t[k]=a_1t[k-5]+a_2t_[k-4]+a_3t[k-3]+a_4t[k-2]+a_5t[k-1]$$ yes?

Comment: Working from the program, your polynomial is the characteristic polynomial for the associated linear recursion so, yes, the limit gives you a root.  Here is a good general discussion:  http://www.artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Characteristic_polynomial

Comment: @lulu The program shows the quintic polynomial if you run it in Mathematica. But thank you for the link.

Comment: Sorry, degree 5 is correct.  I always start my coefficients at $a_0$ so I am off by one here.